# Are booby-traps illegal if they don't harm humans?

Tags: united-states, liability, property

I saw this image today:

[image: 4chan screencap on Facebook]

For the sake of this question, let's assume it happened in the front yard of the poster's house (so on his property)

If this really did happen, would this be considered a booby trap, because the nails served no purpose other than to destroy the property of people driving over the sign?

Would this trap be illegal, even though there's no way that it would reasonably hurt another human (if you're outside, you have shoes on, protecting you from the nails).

Comment: Presuming that somebody outside would have shoes on, is far from reasonable. Nor would shoes of many types and manufacture be protective either.

Comment: You cannot booby trap your property, even against trespassers (or police) and even if you feel that no reasonable person would be hurt: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/can-i-booby-trap-my-property-against-police/ and http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6792/am-i-liable-if-trespassers-on-my-private-property-injure-themselves And I would doubt very much that "story" from 4chan/Facebook; think for a minute where it came from.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch This kind of thing happens all the time when 4chan gets involved. While it's always possible to embellish a story, this honestly seems to be truthful.

Comment: @user4657, presuming somebody would step on a board bristling with spikes is far from reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot booby trap your property, see [Can I booby-trap my property against police?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/can-i-booby-trap-my-property-against-police?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can, however, protect your property in any reasonable way that will not cause harm to innocent trespassers. So things like fences with *obvious* barbed wire, road spikes that would damage tires but not people etc. From the images it *seems* like the nature of the spikes are such that they would injure someone who stepped on or fell on them and probably cross the line into booby trap territory.

Comment: So if these were the spikes you see on roads (with signs saying "wrong way") that'd be OK?

Comment: I take it as spikes like these http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/drivingworld-htif/images/4/4f/Road_spikes.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120401082221 are ok as they are obvious but the spikes in your picture are not. the spikes should be a deterrent not revenge after the action

Comment: You could make an argument that the spikes in the image are okay, since the campaign signs are marking their location and make it difficult to accidentally approach them.

Comment: "Booby trap" in law is often defined as a contraption that causes grave bodily harm or death. Something designed to burst tires would be very unlikely to be considered a booby trap in law. However, you might still risk legal trouble if someone injured themselves on them anyway...

Comment: Something designed to burst tires can easily cause grave bodily harm or death.

Comment: @gnasher729 But a booby trap is often defined as being _designed_ to do that.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it cited actual law or case law on jut what constitutes an unlawful "booby trap".

Comment: @gnasher729, nails don't burst tires, they cause them to slowly deflate.

Comment: @MichaelHall As someone who had flat tires often enough: steering can get *very hard* once the tire starts to deflate, and that makes driving them very unsafe and is *very likely* to cause a crash if the deflation is fast enough, due to several signs which shredd the tires. However, [installation of Spike Strips is **VERY MUCH** illegal anyway](https://www.findlaw.com/legalblogs/criminal-defense/can-you-install-spike-strips-in-your-driveway/), unless you have fenced your yard. Even a [manufacturer of Spike stris](https://roadshark.com/tire-shredder-spike-strips/) warns not to do so privately.