# Liability for a driver hitting a concrete-filled pumpkin on purpose

Tags: united-states, liability, driving, motor-vehicle, vandalism

This [YouTube short video](https://youtube.com/shorts/2ejhGzWqV3M?feature=share) describes a man (let's call him Peter) who has placed Halloween pumpkins at the end of his driveway, only to have the pumpkins intentionally run over by car drivers, so as a booby trap, he places a large concrete-filled pumpkin at the end of his driveway. A driver then drives his car into the pumpkin intentionally, expecting to smash the pumpkin, and instead breaks an axle.

In the above scenario, is Peter liable for damages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are booby-traps illegal if they don't harm humans?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/are-booby-traps-illegal-if-they-dont-harm-humans)

Comment: The linked question is significantly different,  (albeit related) because the nails shown in the image could easily harm a pedestrian, and the tire-blowouts them seem designed to cause could  plausibly harm an occupant of a car. The "pumpkins" described here do not fit either of these characteristics. IMO this should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: So to crash my car, I have to leave the public road, drive along Peters presumably private driveway right to his house, and then try to destroy his property?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't this really boil down to: If I damage my own equipment or tools while illegaly trying to damage someone else's property, can I hold the 'someone else' liable for the damage to my equipment?

Comment: After years of kids taking baseball bats to mailboxes on our street, my next-door neighbor built a replacement out of high-tensile steel used for shipbuilding. The rest of the street never lost a mailbox again.